# Angular 4 on click function - how to use returned value?

Tags: angular

I need help with on click function in Angular 4. I've got such an element:

```
      <mat-cell *matCellDef="let row">
        <span>{{row.messageText | hasString}}</span>
        <span *ngIf="row.messageText && row.messageText.length >= 30"><span class="show-more" (click)="showMore(row)">more</span></span>
      </mat-cell>
```

I have a string in table cell from row.messageText, which is cut into shorter string by *ngIf directive. If length of the string is too much, I shorten it by substr() function. and display in the table cell. I also add a "more" span to it so I can click on it and expand this string.

And there is my problem - what can I do so I can click on "more" and show entire length of this string? My idea is to bind on click function to span "show more" and return a full string.

This is the function in my component .ts file:

```
showMore(row) {
  return row.messageText.substr();
}
```

The function returns full string. How can I apply this to my component.html?

Answer (score 1):

You can call the function within the expression

```
<span>{{showMore(row)}}</span>
```

Answer (score 1):

You can send custom parameter `showFullString` to your `hasString` pipe.

```
@Pipe({name: 'hasString'})
export class hasString implements PipeTransform {
    /**
     *
     * @param value
     * @returns {String}
     */
    transform(value: String, showFullString:Boolean): String {
        if(showFullString) {
          return value;
        }else {
          return value.substr() ; //substring as per your requirement.
        } 
    }
}
```

This showFullString Boolean can be toggled from showMore method :

```
showMore(row) {
  this.showFullString = true;
}
```